# How to add https url on target prometheus

Tags: https, prometheus

I want to add my HTTPS target URL to Prometheus, an error like this appears:

```
"https://myDomain.dev" is not a valid hostname"
```

my domain can access and run using proxy pass Nginx with port 9100(basically I made a domain for node-exporter)

my configuration prometheus.yml

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9090']

  - job_name: 'domain-job'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['https://myDomain.dev']
```

is there any more configuration to add?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use the following configuration:

```
  - job_name: 'domain-job'
    scheme: https
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['myDomain.dev']
```

Answer (score 10):

Besides configuring the https scheme, if you need to skip the tls or need to configure a bearer token, this config will work:

```
job_name: 'spring-actuator'
  scheme: https
  authorization:
      type: Bearer
      credentials: <your_token>
  tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
  metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
  scrape_interval: 5s
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['your_ip:your_port']
```

If you need other configuration, this [reference](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/) might help you.